# Karma unit test for ES6 modules with babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine, babeljs

I'm following instructions from [karma-babel-preprocessor](https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor) to set up unit tests in a project I'm currently working, but I always the error

'require is not defined'

My karma.conf.js is as follows:

```
files: [
   { pattern: './test/unit/*.spec.js', watched: true },
   { pattern: './src/js/es6_modules/*.js', watched: false },
],

preprocessors: {
    './src/js/es6_modules/*.js': ['babel'],
    './test/unit/*.spec.js': ['babel'] //, 'coverage'
},

babelPreprocessor: {
  options: {
    presets: ['es2015'],
    sourceMap: 'inline'
  },
  filename: function (file) {
    return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
  },
  sourceFileName: function (file) {
    return file.originalPath;
  }
}
```

The scripts in src/js/es6_modules jave ES6 classes exported. Something like:

```
export default class MyClass {

}
```

And my spec file would need to import this

```
import { MyClass } from "../../src/js/es6_modules/myclass";
```

I have seen some thread here at SO that said I would need to use browserify, but I can't find any doc (or example) on how to use it together with babel in karma. Does anyone know to configure this properly?

Comment: How do you handle modules in production?

Comment: @zeroflagL with browserify and babelify. I changed the preprocessor in karma.conf.js, now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using browserify instead of babel, and using a babelify transform

```
preprocessors: {
    './src/js/es6_modules/*.js': ['browserify'],
    './test/unit/*.spec.js': ['browserify']
},

browserify: {
    debug: true,
    "transform": [
  [
    "babelify",
    {
      presets: ["es2015"]
    }
  ]
]
},
```